# Colocar o nome de um campo id com um dado de dentro de um @foreach

Tags: html5, laravel, angular

```
<?php counter = 0 ?>
@foreach($buildings as $building)
  <?php
    $var1 = counter;
    $counter = counter + 1;
  ?>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         id="campo{{counter}}"
         name="campo{{counter}}><td>{{$name_building}}</td>
  <br />
@endforeach
```

Como resolver isso? 
Se tem dois itens dentro `foreach`, deveria ficar assim

```
<input type="checkbox" id=campo1 name=campo1...
<input type="checkbox" id=campo2 name=campo2...
```

Como eu atribuo um campo dentro de um `foreach` dentro do `HTML`?

Comment: não entendi bem, o que deseja fazer ???

Comment: Virgilio Novic: eu preciso nomear o input...colocar o id com o nome que vem dento do foreach...tipo campo[1] campo[2] campo[3]... mas isso o html nao permite, entao como eu devo fazer? para cada campo do checkbox deve ter um nome diferente e como fazer isso?

Comment: Basicamente: `<input type="checkbox" value="{{$nome do campo}}">`!

Comment: certo, mas eu nao preciso de value, eu preciso do id do campo, vou melhorar a pergunta...

Comment: Basicamente: `<input type="checkbox" id="{{$nome do campo}}">` é só colocar o campo e o valor internamente!

Comment: id="campo{{counter}}" e counter sendo um contador dentro do foreach e o que estou tentando agora...obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: Resolvido! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize [$loop->iteration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#loops) que vai disponibilizar a posição de cada item desse `foreach`, exemplo:

```
@foreach($buildings as $building)
  <input type="checkbox" 
         id="campo{{ $loop->iteration }}"
         name="campo{{ $loop->iteration }}><td>{{$name_building}}</td>
  <br />
@endforeach
```

[esse recurso é a partir do Laravel 5.3](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/the-new-loop-variable-in-laravel-5-3/) e auxilia na sua dúvida.

---

Se a versão for abaixo do Laravel 5.3 faça assim:

```
@foreach($buildings as $index => $building)
  <input type="checkbox" 
         id="campo{{ $index + 1 }}"
         name="campo{{ $index + 1 }}><td>{{$name_building}}</td>
  <br />
@endforeach
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito!
Obrigado!